# Uploading file on ftp server in grails

Tags: grails, ftp

I am developing a app in grails where I have some images & I need to upload on ftp server.I have tried lot of things but still not getting any success.
What is best way to upload image file on ftp server through grails?

Answer (score 0):

By far one of the best solutions is the [Commons Virtual File System](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/api.html) (Commons VFS) library which works great within any Java or Groovy project. I've used it in many Grails applications for communicating with FTP servers (server to server).

You can add Commons VFS to your Grails project as a dependency in your `BuildConfig.groovy` like this::

```
dependencies {
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-vfs2:2.0'
}
```

Here is just an example of how you could expose the use of Commons VFS through a Grails service:

```
// VirtualFileSystemService.groovy
package com.example

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean

import java.net.URLEncoder

import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemManager
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.VFS
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.Selectors
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileType

class VirtualFileSystemService implements InitializingBean {

    static transactional = false

    FileSystemManager vfs = VFS.getManager()
    FileSystemOptions vfsFileSystemOptions = new FileSystemOptions()

    void afterPropertiesSet() {
        // setup FTP file system options
        FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setPassiveMode(vfsFileSystemOptions, true)
        FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(vfsFileSystemOptions, true)
        FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setDataTimeout(vfsFileSystemOptions, 180000)
    }

    boolean exists(Map settings, String container, String fileName) {
        FileObject fo = resolveFile(settings, container, fileName)
        boolean file_exists = fo?.exists() ?: false
        fo.close()
        return file_exists
    }

    List listFiles(Map settings, String container, String fileName) {
        List results = []
        FileObject fo = resolveFile(settings, container, fileName)
        if (!fo.exists()) return results

        List files = fo.getChildren()
        files.each {
            results << [
                type: (it.getType() == FileType.FOLDER) ? 'FOLDER' : 'FILE',
                name: it.getName().getBaseName(),
                size: (it.getType() == FileType.FILE) ? it.getContent().getSize() : 0
            ]
        }

        fo.close()
        return results
    }

    void delete(Map settings, String container, String fileName) {
        FileObject fo = resolveFile(settings, container, fileName)
        if (fo.exists() == true) fo.delete(Selectors.SELECT_ALL)
        fo.close()
    }

    void rename(Map settings, String container, String fileName, String newFileName) {
        FileObject fo = resolveFile(settings, container, fileName)
        if (fo.exists() == false) return

        FileObject nfo = resolveFile(settings, container, newFileName)
        fo.doRename(nfo)
        fo.close()
        nfo.close()
    }

    void createDirectory(Map settings, String container, String fileName) {
        FileObject fo = resolveFile(settings, container, fileName)
        if (fo.exists() == true) return
        fo.createFolder()
        fo.close()
    }

    void upload(Map settings, String container, String fileName, InputStream data) {
        log.debug("Save file ${fileName} to ${container}")

        FileObject pfo = resolveFile(settings, container, null)
        log.debug("Parent exists?: " + pfo.exists())

        FileObject fo = resolveFile(settings, container, fileName)
        if (fo.exists() == false) {
            try {
                fo.createFile()
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e)
                log.error(e.getMessage())
                throw e
            }
        } else {
            fo.delete()
            fo.createFile()
        }

        long bytesCopied = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(data, fo.content.outputStream)

        log.debug("${bytesCopied} bytes uploaded.")
        fo.close()
    }

    OutputStream download(Map settings, String container, String fileName) {
        FileObject fo = resolveFile(settings, container, fileName)
        if (fo.exists() == false) return null

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(fo.content.inputStream, outputStream)
        fo.close()

        return outputStream
    }

    FileObject resolveFile(Map settings, String container, String fileName) {
        // add any leading forward slash to container if not present
        if (!container.startsWith("/")) {
            container = "/" + container
        }
        // remove any trailing slash from container if present
        if (container.endsWith("/")) {
            container = container.substring(0, container.length() -1)
        }
        String path = "${container}/${fileName}"
        if (!fileName) path = "${container}"

        log.debug("resolving path for ftp://${URLEncoder.encode(settings['username'])}:${URLEncoder.encode(settings['password'])}@${settings['host']}${path}")
        return vfs.resolveFile("ftp://${URLEncoder.encode(settings['username'])}:${URLEncoder.encode(settings['password'])}@${settings['host']}${path}", vfsFileSystemOptions)
    }
}
```